# keeping track of words in android text to speech module

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am trying to build an app where the device reads a story using the tts module and when it arrives at a particular word, I want to show an image. My TTS module is working fine, is there anyway I can know what word is the text to speech module speaking so that I can fetch the appropriate image ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, chunk your reading into small several words each. Each time your apps starts speaking, set a particular [KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.Engine.html#KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID). Then when then use the [onStart](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/UtteranceProgressListener.html) callback to know when the app is speaking the particular `KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID`.